# SQL server: WHERE in xml field

Tags: sql-server

Example: I have table TableA with 3 records:

record 1:

```
id = 1, value = '<Employee id='1' name='Employee1'></Employee><Employee id='2' name='Employee2'></Employee>'
```

record 2:

```
id = 2, value = '<Employee id='1' name='Employee1'></Employee><Employee id='2' name='Employee2'></Employee><Employee id='3' name='Employee3'></Employee>'
```

record 3:

```
id = 3, value = '<Employee id='1' name='Employee1'></Employee><Employee id='2' name='Employee2'></Employee><Employee id='3' name='Employee3'></Employee><Employee id='4' name='Employee4'></Employee>'
```

the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE...
```

How can I put the where clause to get only record 1?

Many thanks,

Comment: `WHERE id = 1`? (doesn't match the question asked in the title but matches the one asked in the question body)

Comment: Thank you! but I want to get record 1 with another where clause :(

Comment: Do you mean `Employee` with attribute id = 1, or the first Employee element of each row?

Comment: I mean: If I have employeeId = 1 and employeeId = 2, how can I get record that only contains employeeId = 1 and employeeId = 2:
(record 1 match: id = 1, value = '<Employee id='1' name='Employee1'></Employee><Employee id='2' name='Employee2'></Employee>')

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the data is that it doesn't contain well formed `xml` - you will need to wrap it before you can use the xml tools in Sql like `xquery`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Nodes.node.value('(./@id)[1]', 'int') AS EmployeeId,
    Nodes.node.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS EmployeeName
  FROM
    (
       SELECT CAST('<xml>' + value + '</xml>' AS Xml) As WrappedXml
       FROM TableA
    ) AS x
    cross apply x.WrappedXml.nodes('//Employee') as Nodes(node)
) as y
WHERE 
   y.EmployeeId = 1;
```

- Inner select -wraps the xml
- Middle select - standard xquery
- Outer select - where filter

You haven't clarified what you mean w.r.t. `get only record 1`, but if you mean just the first element of each row (which coincidentally also has id = 1), you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a sequence:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Nodes.node.value('(./@id)[1]', 'int') AS EmployeeId,
    Nodes.node.value('(./@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS EmployeeName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.Id ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 )) SequenceId
  FROM
    (
       SELECT Id, CAST('<xml>' + value + '</xml>' AS Xml) As WrappedXml
       FROM TableA
    ) AS x
    cross apply x.WrappedXml.nodes('//Employee') as Nodes(node)
) as y
WHERE SequenceId = 1;
```

[Both Fiddles here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3074/2)

Comment: But I'm sorry! I didn't explain clearly my question!
If in TableA have 3 records. If I have employeeId = 1 and employeeId = 2. How can I query in TableA to get record with value field only contains employeeId = 1 and employeeId = 2. It means record 1 match the requiredment.

record 1:
 = 1, value = '<Employee id='1' name='Employee1'></Employee><Employee id='2' name='Employee2'></Employee>'

Record 2 don't match because It contains 
employeeId = 3. Record 3 don't match because it contains EmployeeId=  3 and employId = 4

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this query and It returns record 1 as I expect:

SELECT * FROM TableA
    WHERE value.exist('(Employee[@id = 1])') = 1 and value.exist('(Employee[@id = 2])') = 1 AND value.value('count(Employee[@id])', 'int') = 2

Do you have any comments for this query? Should I use it? :)